# ld: library not found for -lCocoaLumberjack | React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have tried rebuilding project, npm install, linking, opening xsworkspace file everything. Nothing is working! The error still comes up:

> ld: library not found for -lCocoaLumberjack
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

rebuilding project, npm install, linking, opening xsworkspace file everything

Error xcode

[image]

Comment: platform :ios, '8.0'

# You need to set target when you use CocoaPods 1.0.0 or later.
target 'SampleTarget' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end

Comment: That didn't work

https://i.imgur.com/wkoOzOr.png